# How do I install the Unity Editor on Linux?

Tags: unity, linux

I have installed Unity trough the Hub but still need the editor. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that? I'm running a Ubuntu based Linux system. I already have MonoDevelop installed I just need the darn editor.

I then get greeted with the following popup but nowhere does it give me the chance to install the editor.

[image]

Comment: Presumably you went to the [Installs tab of the Hub and clicked the Add button](https://i2.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unity-hub.jpg?fit=800%2C532&ssl=1)? What do you see when you try that?

Comment: I have made an edit

Comment: The editor is what you're installing. That dialog is just choosing what optional parts to add *in addition to* the editor. Did you try continuing with the installation past this screen to test if it works?